# Laravel Passport Frontend Quickstart

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I am new to laravel. I tried using Laravel Passport for API Authentication.

Everything is going correct, but when i am using view component to add clients using UI, it`s showing ERROR "Request faild with Error 404".

Regards.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhF2R.png)

[Browser UI and Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmElQ.png)

Comment: Both image links are the same. Do you have the route set in `routes/api.php`?

Comment: @ Eddy- I am using routes/web.php

Comment: @ Eddy- I have updated the image link, please go through it.

Comment: All the `404` are the missing routes. Go through documentation it says: "Next, you should call the Passport::routes method within the boot method of your  AuthServiceProvider. This method will register the routes necessary to issue access tokens and revoke access tokens, clients, and personal access tokens:"

Comment: @ Eddy- It`s Already Done!